# Two category document classification using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, document-classification

I am messing around with sklearn and support vector machines to classify documents. The categories that I am looking to place the documents in are {course, non-course} where course represents web page text consisting of classes offered in a college major and non-course anything else.

This class that I constructed to do this is akin to this one:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import metrics

class TestSVG(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                                  ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                                  ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', alpha=1e-3, random_state=42)),
                                ])

        self.grid_params = {'vect__ngram_range' : [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
                            'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
                            'clf__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3),
                           }

        self.gs_clf = GridSearchCV(self.text_clf, self.grid_params, n_jobs=-1)
        self.training_target = []
        self.training_data = []
        self.testing_data = []
        self.testing_target = []

        self.classifier = None

    def train(self, training_data, training_target):
        self.training_data = training_data
        self.training_target = training_target
        self.classifier = self.gs_clf.fit(self.training_data, self.training_target)

    def predict(self, text):    
        if isinstance(text, basestring):
            text = [text]       
        elif not isinstance(text, list):
            raise ValueError("Input for prediction must be text of a list")

        if self.classifier is None:
            raise ValueError("Classifier must be trained to make predictions.")

        return self.classifier.predict(text)

    def test(self, testing_data, testing_target):
        self.testing_data = testing_data
        self.testing_target = testing_target

        predicted = self.classifier.predict(self.testing_data)
        return np.mean(predicted == testing_target)
```

To gather the training data for the courses, I have written some webscraping classes that scrape the text for a set of webpages whose base urls I hardcoded.

I am stuck at this point. My initial strategy was to reference course description pages as non-course documents. However, because I categorize documents as courses and then basically "anything else", I am unsure whether I should be using related content or totally unrelated content such as a set of predefined wikipedia pages for the non-course documents.

The reason that I planned on using the course descriptions is that my ultimate plan is to use scrapy to create a web-link graph. I can then traverse the graph, scrape text, and find unknown course listing pages using the support vector machine. My worry is that I would get false positives if the svm was not trained this way.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have training data resemble the testing data (or the data which you will predict on) as much as possible. IMHO the data for non-course should consist of both slightly related documents (e.g: journal documents and totally unrelated documents (sport news).

Comment: Let's say I was to use a more robust set of categories, including related documents such as academic journals and unrelated text like news. If I ignored the use of course description pages for a "non-course" category opting instead to just use the university pages for course listings for the "course" category, would I have sufficient strategy for classifying these documents even if I am traversing and checking all text in a given university web domain for course listings?

Comment: Yes this seems to be a good strategy. You'll train your model to classify all pages in university domain as "course" and "non-course"